# Prism Regions Not Disposing Views or ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I assumed that Prism Regions would automatically detect and call `Dispose` any views or view models that implemented the `IDisposable` interface.  Turns out I was wrong.

I then considered implementing `IActiveAware` so I could dispose my views/viewmodels on my own, but that seems rather hackish.  I'd rather have it done automatically.

How can I configure Prism Regions to automatically dispose my views and view models that implement `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching far and wide on the internet, and not finding any real solution, I developed my own custom `RegionBehavior`, which turned out to work very nicely.

The behavior listens to the region's view collection for any changes, and when any are **removed**, it checks for and calls `Dispose` on the view and/or view model, only if they implement `IDisposable`.

```
class DisposeClosedViewsBehavior : RegionBehavior
{
    protected override void OnAttach()
    {
        Region.Views.CollectionChanged += Views_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Views_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove) return;

        foreach (var removedView in e.OldItems)
        {
            IDisposable disposableView = removedView as IDisposable;
            IDisposable disposableViewModel;

            var iviewView = removedView as IView;
            if (iviewView != null)
            {
                disposableViewModel = iviewView.DataContext as IDisposable;
            }
            else
            {
                var frameworkElementView = removedView as FrameworkElement;
                disposableViewModel = frameworkElementView?.DataContext as IDisposable;
            }

            disposableView?.Dispose();
            disposableViewModel?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The final step is to plug this behavior into prism by overriding the bootstrapper `ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors` method:

```
protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
{
    var factory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();

    factory.AddIfMissing(nameof(DisposeClosedViewsBehavior), typeof(DisposeClosedViewsBehavior));

    return factory;
}
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: One small remark : null check missing for disposableViewModel

Comment: @Nikita There is null checking in there.  It's using the new C# 6 null check `?`.

Comment: ok. yesterday I tried to search for that but couldn't find any documentation :P will update myself.. thanks :)

Comment: Looks great - I'm using Prism with Xamarin.Forms (Prism.DryIoc.Forms 8.0.0.1909 and Prism.Forms.Regions 8.0.0.1909 )- we don't seem to have a Bootstrapper available. Any idea how to plug the Behavior in on Forms?

Comment: Thank you for this. In your experience, when will the disposed view models be garbage collected? I've implemented this, but the VMs still exist in memory.

Answer (score 8):

Modification of `Nathan A`'s answer for Prism 6 (`IView` was removed) and uses a handy built in helper method to call Dispose an View and ViewModel.

```
class DisposeClosedViewsBehavior : RegionBehavior
{
    protected override void OnAttach() =>
        Region.Views.CollectionChanged += Views_CollectionChanged;

    private void Views_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace))
            return;

        foreach (var removedView in e.OldItems)
            MvvmHelpers.ViewAndViewModelAction<IDisposable>(removedView, d => d.Dispose());
    }
}
```